# Why my linq query projecting one item in the model class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I have more than one item in xml file and want to print all of them. But for some reason, it is only printing first item from the xml file.

Here is my xml file. stored in the database table in a column called XmlFile:-

```
<root>
  <item name="one" action="GetListOne" print="2" />
  <item name="two" action="GetListTwo" print="1" />
  <item name="three" action="GetListThree" print="2" />
  <item name="four" action="GetListFour" print="0" />
</root>
```

Here is my model class:-

```
 public class ItemList 
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Action { get; set; }
        public string Print { get; set; }

    }
```

And Linq:-

```
var items = _repo.GetItemsById(Id).Single();
var xml = XDocument.Parse(items.XmlFile);
var model = from x in xml.Descendants("root")
    select new ItemList
    {
        Name = x.Element("item").Attribute("name").Value,
        Action = x.Element("item").Attribute("action").Value,
        Print = x.Element("item").Attribute("print").Value,
    };
foreach (var m in model)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Name = {0}",m.Name));
}
```

Output:-

Name = One

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always getting first `item` of the root, you need:

```
var model = from x in xml.Descendants("item")
            select new ItemList
            {
                Name = x.Attribute("name").Value,
                Action = x.Attribute("action").Value,
                Print = x.Attribute("print").Value,
            };
```